# Trying to verify that a three character sting is in a specified format

Tags: java, return, charat

[My result after passing the value "A2A" - which should return false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqIF.png)
I want to check that a three character string matches the format 12A. The first two must be a digit and the 3rd must be a letter.
The string "A2A" must therefore return false.
What is happening here and how stupid am I being?

I've tried various ways of doing this and nothing seems to work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, post your code here, nicely formatted. Aside from that, `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is used for comparing equality. So either write `if (v1 == true)` or simply `if (v1)`.

Comment: You assign values in your statements via `=` instead of comparing via `==`. But using a comparison operator for booleans ins not needed anyway. You can just do `if(someBoolean)` directly instead of `if(someBoolean == true)`.

Comment: actually no `if` is needed: `return Character.isDigit(a) && Character.isDigit(b) && ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String#matches()` here with a regular expression:

```java
public boolean validate(String input) {
    return input.matches("[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]");
}
```